# Sublime Text 3 Autoprefix CSS not working

Tags: css, sublimetext3, autoprefixer

I have installed Sublime Text 3 and Autoprefix CSS from package control on my Mac OSX
When I try to run Autoprefix CSS on a CSS3 syntax file, it simply does nothing.

As suggested in other posts I have changed user setting to :

```
{
    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "> 10%", "ff > 4", "opera > 9"]
}
```

But still does nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `node.js` installed?

Comment: Change file ending from .css to .css3

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you install css3 package, I had same problem and find solution here:
http://www.chriseisenbraun.com/news/autoprefixer-not-working-in-sublime-text-3-try-this-one-weird-trick-

> Open a CSS file in Sublime Text
>
> Navigate to View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as… > CSS3
>
> After this step, any file you open in the future will be highlighted
>   using CSS3 syntax

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer,you can try update the setting of Autoprefixer such as: "browsers": ["last 10 version"].I think the reason is browsers' version is so high that vender prefixer can't be completed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://superuser.com/questions/932834/autoprefixer-does-not-work-on-sublime?newreg=21a71fb98e5e4c7c971f842ece7937c9

In your Autoprefix settings (In MacOS: Sublime Text/Preferences/Package Settings/Autoprefixer), instead of putting:

```
{
    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "> 10%", "ff > 4", "opera > 9"]
}
```

Put this:

```
{
    "browsers": ["last 7 versions"],
    "cascade": true,
    "remove": true
}
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In your Autoprefix settings
[**Put This:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWmGE.png)

```
{
"browsers": ["last 5 versions"]
}
```

In your Key Bindings settings
[**Put This:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHnpe.png)

```
/*for windowns*/
{"keys": ["alt+shift+p"],"command": "autoprefixer"}

/*for mac*/
{"keys": ["alt+super+p"],"command": "autoprefixer"}
```

And make sure to you have installed node.js